# Twitter Bootstrap - Print all tab content

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have the basic bootstrap tabs set up with no dynamically inserted content and print specific media queries in my base stylesheet. When the user prints from the browser I want all the tab content to print, not just the active tab. I know there has to be an easy solution to this, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try this in your print media query:

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. That did it. Thanks! I'd upvote you but I'm relatively new to SO.

Comment: Cool -- You should be able to accept the answer by clicking to the left of the number.

Comment: This also helps when trying to generate PDF version of a webpage with PhantomJS

Comment: I needed `visibility: visible !important` too

Comment: Thanks @Luke -- I added that to the answer

Comment: Just what I needed. I also added `page-break-after: always` to get a page break in the print output after each tab section. Plus `.nav-tabs {display:none;}` also in the @media print query gets rid of the tabs themselves

Comment: This works in Chrome but isn't working in Firefox for me.

Answer (score 2):

@Scott's answer didn't work for me, and I think it is because I'm using bootstrap 4.

This is what worked for me in bootstrap 4. I added the display helper classes `d-print-block`, `d-none`, and `d-print-none` where appropriate.

I didn't want the top nav bar to print at all, so I added `d-print-none`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-bordered d-print-none" role="tablist" id="mainTabs">
```

I wanted the individual `tab-pane`s to print if on print media, so I added a header to the tab pane's content and added the `d-none` class so it wouldn't show in the browser, but also added `d-display-block` so it WOULD should in print media. I also added `d-print-media` to the tabpanel div itself so that it would show the entire contents in print media.

```
<div role="tabpanel" class=" fade in show active tab-pane d-print-block" id="myTab">
    <div class="header-title d-none d-print-block">My Tab Name</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, all my info is on a modal, but Chrome doesnt see that and cuts off the modal. Any ideas?