# Expand Bootstrap nav-tabs for printing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I print a page from my browser, I would like to be able to see all tab contents if possible. Currently, I only see the current tab.

Is there anyway to expand all of the individual tab contents for print only?

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1" data-toggle="tab">Property</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" data-toggle="tab">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" data-toggle="tab">Owner</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabs-1">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
              <dt>
                :
    </div>
```

Comment: are the `<li>`s without the `class="active"` normally hidden? And if so with what or how? Have example CSS?

Comment: No. All it does is draw the selected tab, as if you had clicked on it. If there is no `class="active"` for the `<li>` then all the tabs are drawn the same. However, if there is no "active" set for `<div class=tab-pane ...` then the tab content is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Add CSS for printing, depending on how you hide the tabs, changing that to the opposite is a possible solution.
For example something like this "could" work:

```
@media print {
  ul.nav-tabs li {
    display: block;
  }
 }
```

Comment: I found the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963801/twitter-bootstrap-print-all-tab-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963801/twitter-bootstrap-print-all-tab-content) to use `.tab-content > .tab-pane {display: block !important; opacity: 1 !important;}`. Thanks for your replies as it gave me the rigtht angle to search for a solution.

Comment: The `!important` attribute is what I needed. Too bad I didn't think about it before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that :

```
var beforePrint = function() {
    $(".main-content .nav-tabs").each( function() {
        $(this).find("li a").each( function(index, element) {
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('href');
            var tab_text = $(this).text();
            $('<h2 class="print-title-tab">' + tab_text + "</h2>").insertBefore(tab_id);
        });
    });
};
var afterPrint = function() {
    $('.print-title-tab').remove();
};

if (window.matchMedia) {
    var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
    mediaQueryList.addListener(function(mql) {
        if (mql.matches) {
            beforePrint();
        } else {
            afterPrint();
        }
    });
}
window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
window.onafterprint = afterPrint;
```

https://coderwall.com/p/kvx42g/bootstrap-3-tabs-print-friendly

http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

Comment: Thanks but I achieved what I wanted in CSS - see comment to previous answer.